# What does a collector do?

Tags: prometheus

I'm new to Prometheus and getting a grip on the fundamentals but I am struggling what a *collector* is exactly. Is it a high-level abstract concept, or a concrete implementation?

When you read docs about custom exporters they talk about collectors assuming you know what they are, but the only direct definition I can see is in the Glossary:

> A collector is a part of an exporter that represents a set of metrics.
> It may be a single metric if it is part of direct instrumentation, or
> many metrics if it is pulling metrics from another system.

I'm sure this makes perfect sense once you understand it, but for someone writing code what does it actually *mean*?